# I have to go to this screen twice to load data from fetchAndSet in flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

*When I visited the page first time, it just shows circularProgressIndicator. After going back when I visit that page second time, then circularProgressIndicator shows up and other listview.builder appears perfectly. I have updated the code in question. Any kind of help is much appreciated.*

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: Provider.of<AppointmentsProvider>(context, listen: false)
      .fetchAndSetAvailableSlots(),
  builder: (ctx, snapShot) => Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 380,
          child: snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
              ? Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                      secondary: Icon(
                        Icons.alarm,
                      ),
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                      // checkColor: Colors.black,
                      selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                      // tileColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                      title: Text(list[i].time),
                      value: list[i].isSelected,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        onCheckChanged(list[i], list, value);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: () async {
          await Firebase.initializeApp();
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('appointments').add({
            'id': DateTime.now().toString(),
            'date': widget.formatDate,
            'description': 'description etc.',
            'type': 'type etc.',
            'uid': 'uid etc.',
            'timeSlot': timeSlot,
          });
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
        label: Text('Add Now!'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

---here is the fetchAndSet function---

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetAvailableSlots() async {
await Firebase.initializeApp();
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('appointments')
    .where('date', isEqualTo: 'Dec 11, 2021')
    .get();
List<TimeSlot> bookedSlots = [];

data.docs.forEach(
  (element) async {
     FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Questions').doc(userId).get();
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> item = await FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection('appointments')
        .doc('${element.id}')
        .get();

    bookedSlots
        .add(TimeSlot(isSelected: false, time: item.data()['timeSlot']));
  },
);
availableTimeSlots = bookedSlots;
print(bookedSlots);
notifyListeners();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I would suggest moving

> Firebase.initializeApp();

Into your runApp function.

Regarding your second problem it looks like you are using Provider. If so I would suggest passing an bool loading determining wether or not await getting data is still running. Also a Futurebuilder/Streambuilder could be helpful in displaying that data. Your problem sounds like the widget doesnt rebuild if data is fetched

Comment: thank you so much for suggestion. And I am using futureBuilder.

Comment: my pleasure, if this answer helped you please mark it as solved for other people

Answer (score 0):

Before returning the ListView.builder check the list. If the list is empty then return CircularProgressIndicator() and if the list get some data then return the listview. On the other hand add data to bookSlots list inside setState().

Comment: I've updated the code. Any sugestions now?